# CounterClockwise NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, clojure, eclipse-plugin, counterclockwise

I'm running Eclipse Indigo on OSX 10.7.2, and I cannot get counterclockwise to work properly. If I open the REPL view, it will accept input (and display the input), but not actually evaluate any expressions. When I attempt to force a repl reconnect, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException (no stack trace though).

Attempting to load a clojure project into the repl via the run configuration locks up Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a newly reported bug in counterclockwise, according to their developers.

Comment: Hello, the NullPointerException when hitting "reconnect" is new. The problem you're encountering with the "non responsive REPL" is weird, not reported massively by other people. I wonder what causes this on your configuration, :-§

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Eclipse Indigo on Windows so can't help with OSX specifics, however it sounds like your REPL is disconnected (i.e. there is no running Clojure JVM connected to the REPL window to accept and evaluate your expressions).

The following methods all work for me to get a running Counterclockwise REPL and connected JVM:

- Right click on .clj file, use Run As... / Clojure Application
- In the source file editor, use Ctrl+Alt+L to load the current source file (this starts a REPL automatically if not already open)

Comment: Eclipse locks up when I do that.